# php date change to 12 hour format and add gmt +3

Tags: php, date

I am using date as:

```
 $date = date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
```

This inserts it as 24 hour and what I want is 12 hour format and add GMT +3, how can I do that?

Comment: Change the `H:i:s` part to `h:i:s` for 12-hour format.

Comment: thanks what about adding gmt + 3

Comment: Have you read the manual?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: You need to be way more clear in this question... do you want the literal characters "GMT +3"? Do you want to convert the date/time to the timezone of GMT +3? Or do you want to specify that this given date/time is in GMT +3?

Comment: I would like to convert date/time to GMT + 3

Comment: I don't understand the 7 downvotes. It wasn't such a bad question for SO standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the GMT +3 timezone, you could apply this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+3');
```

Although I don't recommend it because PHP [will not longer support that timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php). You might use [one of the supported ones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). And for the date being in 12-hour format use it this way:

```
$date = date('m-d-Y h:i:s');
```

Lowercase `h` [format character](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is for

> 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros

Comment: thanks for the help. I just don't understand the manual.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use

```
  $date = date("m-d-Y h:i:s", strtotime("now +3 GMT"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`date_default_timezone_set("GMT");`    for changing timezone..(replace gmt with +3 timezone name)

`$date = date('m-d-Y h:i:s');` for 12 hour format..

And read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php